# search for a number in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large dataset, in it, Column A has an ID, and in Column B (texts with ID). I want Column C to display if the value exists or not if exists then leave the cell blank if not then show the number which should be in the cell.

[image]

The IDs will start from the first left (as shown in the screenshot).

I used the "=REGEXMATCH(B2:B(A2:A))" but it didn't work.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=MAP(A2:A4,B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(REGEXMATCH(y,x&"")=FALSE,X,"")))
```

To refer full column as input to `MAP()` function, use-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(REGEXMATCH(y,x&"")=FALSE,X,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun24hr, can we add another condition to this formula? If the notes are empty then leave column C blank.

Comment: @RamanSingh Yes, we can. Try `=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),D2:INDEX(D2:D,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,z,IF(AND(REGEXMATCH(y,x&"")=FALSE,z<>""),X,"")))`.